# Struct fields generic over mutability?

Tags: rust

I am working on an ECS implementation in rust, and I've found that the best way to represent a 'Component' is a via a union, since the tag will be lifted out of each value into an array of Vectors instead. The union is 2 words wide, so this essentially doubles how many values i can keep in cache vs an enum, which is very important

However, often an enum is preferred, so i want to be able to convert a union instance to an enum equivalent that is backed by the existing union instance.

This is is a small version of what I have:

```rs
union UnsafeEcsComponent {
    health: Health
}
impl UnsafeEcsComponent {
    fn safe(&mut self, component_type: EcsComponentType) {
        match component_type {
            Health => unsafe { Health(&mut self.health) }
        }
    }

}

enum EcsComponent<'a> {
   Health(&'a mut Health)
}
```

This works pretty well, but I don't always have a mutable reference that I can use `.safe()` on, however changing `EcsComponent` to contain immutable refs would also not be great because i often *do* want operate on the underlying value

So basically, i want to have some way to make `EcsComponent` generic over its mutability, which doesn't seem easy.

I could also split it out into a struct containing the component type and a reference to the value, but this is a bit more clunky, less safe, and doesn't really solve the varying mutability problem

Any suggestions for how I can tackle this without having two nearly identical data structures for immutable and mutable cases respectively?

Comment: Go with what the standard library does and have a `safe` and a `safe_mut`, and two corresponding enums as well. Yes, it's verbose. I think you could have a `enum RefOrMut<'a, T> { Ref(&'a T), Mut(&'a mut T) }`, but you won't do yourself any favors with this at the call site. Lastly: `fn save` needs to be `unsafe` if you pass in the `EcsComponentType`, because the component type could be wrong.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that lol. You're probably right, although it is a pain. I'll see if i can generate them with a macro or something to make my life less hell, and good callout with the unsafe fn signature!

Comment: Well, if you want to go down the rabbit hole, how about extending https://docs.rs/soa_derive/ to work with enums? ;) Something in [this](https://alic.dev/blog/dense-enums) direction.